# Get number of events occurring per hour

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that contains events along with Unix timestamps:

```
event_id | start_time | end_time
----------------------------------
1        | 1485388800 | 1485410400
2        | 1485396000 | 1485403200
3        | 1485406800 | 1485414000
```

I would like to write a query that takes a start time and an end time and tells me how many events are occurring during each hour. The result for the above table, given the start time 1485385200 and the end time 1485414000 would be:

```
event_count | time
------------------------
0           | 1485385200
1           | 1485388800
1           | 1485392400
2           | 1485396000
2           | 1485399600
1           | 1485403200
2           | 1485406800
1           | 1485410400
0           | 1485414000
```

What's the best way to write this query? I am stuck both on generating this range and also on range checking the events, preferably without reading the table more than once since it can be quite large.

Comment: Come on. Try something. (Although I'd handle the logic of missing rows in application code)

Comment: If you want to also have rows for hours where nothing happened, you'll need some kind of calendar table or view to join to - not sure how this is usually done in MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the best approach would be to have some kind of calendar table to join on.

However, here's a (slightly hacky) solution without using such a table. It generates the hours sequence using a variable.

The only thing you need to keep in mind is that you need a table that is large enough for the number of intervals you're trying to create (i.e. a table that has at least as many records as the number of hours between your chosen start and end time). In my example, I've used the built-in `mysql.help_topic` table, but if your `events` table itself is large enough, you could use that (or any other table) instead.

```
SET @x:=1485385200, @y:=1485414000;

SELECT COUNT(event_id) AS event_count, hours.start AS time
FROM (
    SELECT @x AS start, @x := @x + 3600 AS end
    FROM mysql.help_topic
    WHERE @x <= @y
) AS hours
LEFT JOIN events AS e
ON e.start_time < hours.end AND e.end_time > hours.start
GROUP BY hours.start
```

This gives me the following output for the test data you provided:

```
+-------------+------------+
| event_count | time       |
+-------------+------------+
|           0 | 1485385200 |
|           1 | 1485388800 |
|           1 | 1485392400 |
|           2 | 1485396000 |
|           2 | 1485399600 |
|           1 | 1485403200 |
|           2 | 1485406800 |
|           1 | 1485410400 |
|           0 | 1485414000 |
+-------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks bit messy but works. The idea is to make one calendar table using unions and join it with your table . You can pass start time and end time as per your requirement , I have done it for 24 hrs

```
SELECT count(event_id) as event_count,t 
FROM
(
SELECT
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`start_time`), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as start_time,
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`end_time`), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') as end_time,
tmp.*,
event_id
from test
right  JOIN
(
(select concat(date(now()),' ','00:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','01:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','02:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','03:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','04:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','05:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','06:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','07:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','08:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','09:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','10:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','11:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','12:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','13:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','14:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','15:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','16:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','17:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','18:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','19:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','20:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','21:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','22:00') as t)
UNION
(select concat(date(now()),' ','23:00') as t)
)tmp
on(cast(tmp.t as datetime) between DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`start_time`), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') and DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`end_time`), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s'))
)xxx
group by t
```